# Vue architecture example for inspiration

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

**TL;DR; Please share really complex, clean and well structured vue project.**

Hello and thanks for reading!

I have been using react for quite a while. I know how to cook complex application and keep it simple and well structured. 
I have learned Vue and feel I can handle any task. But I am always thinking: Am I using the best solution? Do that code will cause problems in future? etc. Official docs provide [list of projects](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue/blob/master/README.md#projects-using-vuejs). But there are a lot and most of them either simple or messy.

So I'm looking for **vue code samples** (not basic and simple), and just good idea of  **what to use and what I should avoid**. I am interested in code architecture, how should I split files, folders etc. And I would be gratitude for any **good and real live experience** you are ready to share.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may want to check this collection of awesome stuff with Vue, in particular the [projects section](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue/blob/master/README.md#projects-using-vuejs)